# Is this possible to align the text vertically on UILabel?

Tags: objective-c, uilabel

Here is the example:
My label display this text like this:`=/*`

[image]

What I want is let the `=` go upper, and the `*` go lower
Here is something I want:

[image]

....How can I adjust it in UILabel?? Thanks.

Comment: Do you need the `=` to be a superscript and the `*` to be a subscript? Have you tried NSAttributedString if that's the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These other guys don't understand your question… but I do. :-)

There are two ways to do what you want.

1. Find a font that centers every character vertically.
2. Dive into Core Text, get the sizes of each character, and draw the string yourself with each character centered.

For #2, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17328689/vertically-center-text-in-uilabel-depending-on-actual-visible-letter-height) for some sample code.