# Force UILabel bounds to be set to actual bounds (sizeToFit does not work)

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I have a situation where I have a UILabel object whose text is all in all lower case.

If use size to fit, it assume the highest Y point of the font and only shrinks it to that.

[image]

But if there are no capital letters I need the bounding box to shrink to the exact text size.

Do you know how I can create my own sizing function that returns the true bounds of the text as its rendered (not based on the font max and mins)?

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17328689/vertically-center-text-in-uilabel-depending-on-actual-visible-letter-height

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23075693/contenting-deprecated-sizewithfontconstrainedtosize-to-boundingrectwithsizeopt) can also be helpful.

Comment: What I would do is use auto layout and override `intrinsicContentSize`. Figuring out a good size based on the font and contents is up to you.